Comparing sound from the microphone to stored audio file and finding it's position
I have a stored audio file. File format can be anything if it makes difference. Then I have sound being recorded from the device microphone. Let's say it is just some song.
Now I need to find the moment in the audio file that is being recorded currently through the microphone.
I fully understand that raw comparison is obviously not an option, as sound from the microphone by far is not identical to the audio file. What I have tried is finding best matching part of audio file using waveform peaks, but it is not working very well.
Here is how I tried:
//record waveform peaks from the microphone
suspend fun getWaveformPeakFromMic(): List<Int> {
    val sampleRate = 44100
    val bufferSize = 882 // 200ms buffer size for more frequent peaks

    val duration = calculateBufferDuration(bufferSize, sampleRate)
    Log.d("WaveformPeaks", "Buffer duration: $duration")
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        return emptyList()
    }
    val audioRecord = AudioRecord(
        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
        sampleRate,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        bufferSize
    )

    val waveformPeaks = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val buffer = ShortArray(bufferSize)

    audioRecord.startRecording()
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(5000)
        Log.d("WaveformPeaks", "Stopping audio recording")
        audioRecord.stop()
        audioRecord.release()
    }

    var read = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffer.size)
    while (read > 0) {
        val peak = buffer.maxOf { abs(it.toInt()) }
        waveformPeaks.add(peak)
        read = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, buffer.size)
    }
    Log.d("WaveformPeaks", "WaveformPeaks size: ${waveformPeaks.size}")


    return waveformPeaks
}

//get waveform peaks from the audio file
fun getWaveformPeaksFromPCM(filePath: String, ): List<Int> {
    val bufferSize = 882 // 200ms buffer size for more frequent peaks
    val waveformPeaks = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val byteArray  = readFileFromAssets(this, filePath)
    val shortBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer()
    val buffer = ShortArray(bufferSize)

    while (shortBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        val length = minOf(buffer.size, shortBuffer.remaining())
        shortBuffer.get(buffer, 0, length)
        val peak = buffer.take(length).maxOf { abs(it.toInt()) }
        waveformPeaks.add(peak)
    }

    Log.d("WaveformPeaks", "WaveformPeaks size: ${waveformPeaks.size}")

    return waveformPeaks
}

The audio file is currently the PCM raw audio (that I made from the mp3 using FFMpeg)
And here's how I tried to fond the matching time:
fun findIndex(full:IntArray, part:IntArray) {

        val (bestMatchIndex, likenessCoefficient) = findBestMatch(full, part)
        if (bestMatchIndex != -1) {
            Log.d("FindMic", "Matching subarray found at position ${bestMatchIndex * 0.02}, likeness coefficient: $likenessCoefficient")
        } else {
            Log.d("FindMic", "Matching subarray not found")
        }
    }

fun findBestMatch(full: IntArray, part: IntArray): Pair<Int, Double> {
        var bestMatchIndex = -1
        var bestMatchDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY

        for (i in 0..(full.size - part.size)) {
            val subArray = full.sliceArray(i until (i + part.size))
            val distance = dtwDistance(subArray, part)
            if (distance < bestMatchDistance) {
                bestMatchDistance = distance
                bestMatchIndex = i
            }
        }
        val likenessCoefficient = 1 / (1 + bestMatchDistance) // Example coefficient calculation
        return Pair(bestMatchIndex, likenessCoefficient)
    }

fun dtwDistance(seq1: IntArray, seq2: IntArray): Double {
        val n = seq1.size
        val m = seq2.size
        val dtw = Array(n + 1) { DoubleArray(m + 1) { Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY } }
        dtw[0][0] = 0.0

        for (i in 1..n) {
            for (j in 1..m) {
                val cost = Math.abs(seq1[i - 1] - seq2[j - 1]).toDouble()
                dtw[i][j] = cost + minOf(dtw[i - 1][j], dtw[i][j - 1], dtw[i - 1][j - 1])
            }
        }
        return dtw[n][m]
    }

So curently it just does not work - it shows totally random positions as best matching, and coeficient of likeness is like 2.4996687938848104E-6
So finally to the question: How do I properly find the moment of time played through the microphone? I am open to any ways including 3rd-party libraries, external services, even paid, suggesting on implementing this on the backend, etc.

try asking on the [dsp.se] SE. that looks like a matter of finding a good approach, not a matter of coding. -- why are you trying to reinvent that? there's plenty of existing research and publication on that. instead of hacking some code, you should browse the literature.

Does this help? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar

Most score following (which your problem is an example of) technology relies on mel weighted cepstral coefficients.
